# Spring-boot and appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-boot

I try to use spring-boot with appengine.

For now, I can start spring-boot with mvn spring-boot:run and appengine with mvn appengine:devserver.

But, when I start appengine, I can't get my REST url (404 WARNING: No file found for: /hello)

What did I miss? Can you give me some doc for this ?

Regards

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-servlet-2-5) on deploying to a Servlet 2.5 container?

Answer (score 5):

Google App Engine only supports Servlet 2.5. This can be a bit of an issue when using spring boot since that does not officially support Servlet 2.5.

However, there is a Spring Boot Legacy project which can help you deploy spring boot applications on Servlet 2.5. That can be found at https://github.com/scratches/spring-boot-legacy.

There is also an example of using Spring boot in conjunction with GAE, https://github.com/scratches/spring-boot-sample-gae.